# OpenCV iOS vs Android

Tags: android, ios, opencv

I am working on porting some opencv code I wrote for openCV on iOS.  I am confused as to why the sytax is at all different, considering they were both written in c++, under the same version of openCV (2.4.3).

I am trying to use some array processing methods, such as this one

```
//iOS Code
cv::Mat image;//this comes from each live frame from the camera
float m[] =    { 1.0, 2.0,  1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0};
cv::Mat kernel = cv::Mat(3, 3, CV_32F, m);
int ddepth = -1;
cv::filter2D(image, image, ddepth, kernel);
```

This compiles and works fine on iOS.  When copied to an Android environment, it claims I need to use input arrays and output arrays, not cv::Mat's.  I've tried casting them like this

```
cv::filter2D((InputArray)image, (OutputArray)image, ddepth, kernel);
```

And that compiles, but fails at runtime due to an incorrect conversion.  Can someone help me understand this discrepancy, or how to fix it please?

Comment: do you use a wrapper for android of some sort? Or just calling native through JNI? Beacuse manual clearly says "Mat& dst, Mat& src".

Comment: filter2D takes input/output array. I don't see in your code snipit where you define image.

Comment: I am using an external c++ file compiled by the CDT plugin.  And I have edited my answer to include the image.  In both cases though (iOS and Android) the sent in frame is of the type cv::Mat

Comment: Your iOS snippet must compile for Android as is. Probably there is a problem in your Android environment, say you are using OpenCV headers from one release but links with libs from another OpenCV version.